# Reading table values per column

Tags: jquery

I have two columns in my table and the rows are created dynamically.

```
<table id ="datatable">
  <tr> 
    <td> 
      <input type ="text"> 
    </td>
    <td> 
      <input type ="text"> 
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

For each row, I want to get the value of each table and insert them in an object as follows.

```
var reading= new Object();
reading.Name = (column1).value
reading.Value = (column2).value
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//fetching lines
$('table tr').each(function(){
  var reading = new Object();

  reading.name = $(this).find('td:first input').val();
  reading.value= $(this).find('td:last  input').val();

});
```

**Updated: set error message if  is empty**

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
  var reading = new Object();

  name = $(this).find('td:first');
  reading.name = name.find('>input').val();
  if(reading.name == '')
  {
    name.append('<span>field empty</span>');
  }

  value = $(this).find('td:last');
  reading.value = value.find('>input').val();
  if(reading.value == '')
  {
    value.append('<span>field empty</span>');
  }

});
```

Comment: Using the above code, I can see that it`s also reading the header values. How can I avoid reading the header values?

Comment: what do mean about header values? u mean <th> tags or what?)

Comment: yes <th> tag.  
Just wanted to ask another question:
I want to display an error message if the input is null.
Either I can append a td each time to a row how can I do that? I have tried, and I can see the number of columns increasing. Or Much better, How can I modify the the last td to insert a label in it?

Comment: it should not read <th> tags couz there is a filter find('td:first input'). If you want to indicate that the field is empty you can add error message right after the <input> field in your <td> cell. See example in updated post above.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful.  Now another issue, let`s say the user once more leave the error and I can see that there are twice the same error message displayed.  How can I correct that?

Comment: You can remove <span> element from the cell when user change value in input field. Something like this: $('table td input').change(function(){$(this).parent().find('span').remove()});

Answer (score 0):

You could use a selector that gets all the input types that are in table cells and then iterate through each of them using the [each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
// Get the selector.
var selector = $("#datatable tr td input[type='text']");

// Create the object.
var reading = {};

// Cycle through the inputs, attaching the properties.
selector.each(function (index, element) {
    // If index is 0, then set the name property.
    if (index === 0) reading.Name = $(this).val();

    // If index is 1, set the value property.
    if (index === 1) reading.Value = $(this).val();
});
```

Note, the selector doesn't have to be so exact.  A simple selector such as `#datatabe input` would work in this case as well (assuming all of your input types are text fields).

As for the code, it is heavily reliant on the positional value of the inputs, and that's not a good thing, as layout can easily be changed.  Rather, you might want to attribute your input types with either the name or id attribute, or a custom data attribute (prefixed with "data-", this is an [HTML 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) addition, but is valid for [4.01 strict](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/)), like so:

```
<table id ="datatable">            
  <tr>             
    <td>             
      <input name="Name" type ="text">             
    </td>            
    <td>             
      <input name="Value" type ="text">             
    </td>             
  </tr>            
</table>
```

Then, you can change your code to be more flexible, getting the property name from the attribute value, like so:

```
// Get the selector.
var selector = $("#datatable tr td input[type='text']");

// Create the object.
var reading = {};

// Cycle through the inputs, attaching the properties.
selector.each(function (index, element) {
    // Get the selector for the element.
    var thisSelector = $(this);

    // Set the value accoding to the name on the element.
    reading[thisSelector.attr("name")] = thisSelector.val();
});
```

This way, you can add/remove properties and not have to change your code, as it reads from the attributes on the elements.

Comment: If i`m using <%= Html.textbox()%>, How can I set the name for the textbox?

Comment: @user281180: There is an overload of the TextBox extension method in ASP.NET MVC that takes an object which defines the attributes to assign to the element. You can pass an anonymous type like new { name = "Value" } and it will assign "Value" to the name attribute. Also, I believe there is an overload which takes a string for the name of the textbox as well, since you would commonly use it in form elements.

Comment: Using the above code, I can see that it`s also reading the header values.  How can I avoid reading the header values?